# Why has 100 rep points have been removed from my account?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm not expecting to "make friends" here, but earlier today I was at 153 rep points and now I'm at 51.  What happened and where is this documented?

---

So it looks like it happened again? How did i earn -100 points today?

Who did i offend?

What SE rule(s) were transgressed?

Comment: Your rep history is at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation.

Comment: @TRiG , can you show where the entry is where 100 points are subtracted?

Comment: Nope, because I can't see your rep (I'm not a moderator). Note: The link I provided is to `users/current` (i.e., whoever's looking at it sees their own page), so when I click that link I see *my* rep.

Comment: well, that link shows me losing a 2 points twice (or now three times), when my answer (which was since deleted by *Community*) was voted down.  but it doesn't explain what happened to my (low) rep of 150+.

Comment: There's nothing more I can help you with, I'm afraid. You could try http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=graph. But I am not privy to your rep history, so you'll have to wait till a mod turns up.

Comment: well, i'll have to wait for a mod to turn up.  frankly, there's not a whole lotta mutual trust between myself and the mods (or at least one of the mods).  i check the criteria for an acceptable answer and it said that: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:

    * commentary on the question or other answers
    * asking another, different question
    * “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
    * exact duplicates of other answers
    * barely more than a link to an external site
    * not even a partial answer to the actual question

Answer (score 9):

There are basically three ways you can lose 100 rep:

1. Offer a bounty on a question
2. Have some piece(s) of content you posted within the last 90 days that has votes adding up to 100 rep (10 for answers, 20 for questions) deleted
3. Get docked for offensive content

If its not reason 1 or 2, then it must be reason 3.

Offensive content is judged by anyone on the site flagging a post as such (comment flags don't count for this), and either enough other members (5, I believe) or a moderator agreeing with the flag. At that point you will see the content is marked as deleted "by community" and you will receive a 100 rep point penalty.

In my estimation this is a pretty fair system to incentivize good manners. Most rep changes are weighted in the up direction with even 1 upvote out-weighing up to 5 downvotes but **there are consequences if you cannot keep your self in line and your content respectful**.

**Edit 4:** Removed edits 1 through 3. I stand by my first assessment above, but after that I got distracted and the subsequent edits could be classified as "feeding the trolls". On review I have decided even meta is better off without that mess. The morbidly curious may review the [revision history](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3592/revisions) to see I am not trying to hide even my own mistake, only spare others the mess.

Comment: and still, nowhere is the -100 points explained in any specific action.  they just disappeared.  but no "account entry" (under the *"Recent achievements; reputation, badges, and privileges earned"* menu) is made that reveals that action.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson there is show deleted posts link that will show you the penalty. See the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147283/170797)

Comment: Can I just add that he actually reposted the answer *with* the offensive part. I edited the offensive part out to try and salvage something from the post.

Comment: @DJClayworth Doh. Missed that. I've corrected my post.

Comment: I also added a comment pointing out why I thought what I had deleted was inappropriate, so it's not like he didn't realize the issue.

Comment: well, these guys in Mt 5:20 found something offensive in the truth, too.  so where do you draw the line, guys?  "Christian" militias or hate groups?  or the "Sex with alter boys are our way of life" crowd?

Comment: Clearly not the case here but it is also possible that a higly upvoted question or answer or question with a higly upvoted answer got deleted.

Comment: @Belinda Correct, that is an unlikely but possible scenario that I  left out because I knew this user didn't have anything with that many upvotes that could have been removed, but it is a possible scenario for others. Answering bad-faith questions instead of VTC'ing them is a great way to gain and promptly loose lots of rep on this site.

Answer (score -5):

so it looks like it happened again? how did i earn -100 points today?

who did i offend?

what SE rule(s) were transgressed?

Comment: Robert, as I went through the review queue today there was an old question or answer that you had posted, and when I went to post a comment I discovered that the post of  yours I was working on had disappeared -- been deleted.  I am not sure which one, but it simply disappeared.  As I am not a diamond mod, I regret that I hadn't noted the post's content (there were five questions for review) so I just went to the next one.  I hope one of our diamond mods can clarify.

Comment: i'm not well regarded by the diamond moderators here.  actually David doesn't seem to have a diamond anymore.

Comment: We recently had a mod election as David had to step down. (Real life is one of them things ... ) Our new diamond mods are Peter Turner and Nathaniel.

Comment: but, just to make it clear, **another** 100 points disappeared **today** (or maybe last night). why?

Comment: This post is pointless Robert; you know what's going on so please stop wasting the community's time with this. They can't see your profile history, you can. They can't see your deleted posts, you can. The previous links and instructions from the last time this happened give you the tools to find the post (which I know you've done) and there really isn't much room  for doubt about why the post was inappropriate. Everybody that read it has come to the same conclusion. If you can't constrain yourself to language appropriate for _respectful_ discourse then don't post on this site.

Comment: no, the three questions stand.  (and you're not answering any.)